# Enviar Elementos de un ComboBox por Form. Y que de acuerdo al botón que presione el usuario , este lo enviará al formulario deseado

Tags: php, javascript, html, formularios, select

```
<form action="" id="form" method="POST" >
<select id="controlselect" name="ordenar">
    <option value='0' >Seleccione</option>
    <option value='1' >General</option>
    <option value='2' >Producto</option>
</select>

<input type="submit"  id="BotonBuscar" onclick="Buscar()" value="buscar" />
<input type="submit"  id="BotonGenerar" onclick="Generar()" value="generar" />
</form>
```

1. Tengo el siguiente formulario , con su combobox y dos botones.

   1.1 Quiero que cuando el usuario presione el botón Buscar envíe los elementos del select a mi archivo php Prueba 8 y cuando presione el botón Generar envíe los elementos del select a mi archivo Prueba 9.

   1.2 He estado indagando , pero no hallo la solución , estoy implementando código JavaScript para manipular el form y su propiedad action y tengo algo como esto pero no funciona.

```
function Buscar()
{

document.getElementById('BotonBuscar').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()

    form.setAttribute("action", "Prueba8.php")

})

}


function Generar()

{
  document.getElementById('BotonGenerar').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()

    form.setAttribute("action", "Prueba9.php")

  })

}
```

1.3 Es posible hacer esta manipulación?¿ , si es así , entonces pueden facilitarme el código bien elaborado y explicado, en base a lo que tengo o alguna solución mejor.

Agradecido de Antemano!

Comment: No te va a funcionar porque estas haciendo un `e.preventDefault()` el cual previene el submit de tu `input` por eso no te manda a la página, en sí para que necesitas mandar tu información a ese archivo? Puedes usar AJAX.

Comment: He probado con AJAX , pero elaborando el código me capta los valores del select , mas no me abre los nuevos archivos. ¿Tienes un pequeño ejemplo , que me pueda servir para practicarlo ?

Comment: Al "abrir" te refieres a que te redirija a la página?

Comment: Correcto el debe abrir la pagina porque alli tengo un codigo que debe ejecutar de acuerdo a los valores del SELECT.

Comment: Puedes utilizar un `<a href="prueba8.php?valor=${select}"></a>` creado con JS al momento de que seleccione un valor, osea al `change` y mandar ese valor del `select` por `GET` y obtenerlo en tu archivo PHP como `$_GET['valor']`.

Comment: Pero, el problema está en que no importa el valor del Select , lo que debe captar es el valor del botón. Ejemplo:

Si el usuario le da clic al botón buscar , le envías por post, los valores del select a la pagina prueba 8

Si el usuario le da clic al boton generar , le envías por post los valores del select a la pagina prueba 9

Comment: Por eso, en vez de un botón, agrégale un `<a href=""></a>` y eso te enviará a la página que quieras, te dejo un ejemplo como respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo comentarios en el código, haz la prueba y cualquier duda hazla saber. :D

```js
//Creamos variables para ahorrarnos el document....
let btnBuscar = document.getElementById('Buscar');
let btnGenerar = document.getElementById('Generar');

//agregamos un listener al select para obtener su valor cuando cambie
document.getElementById('controlselect').addEventListener('change', function(e){

let valor = this.value;

//le agregamos el href a la etiqueta <a> para mandarnos a la página que deseamos
btnBuscar.setAttribute('href',`pagina8.php?valor=${valor}`);
btnGenerar.setAttribute('href',`pagina9.php?valor=${valor}`);

//para que observes su href correspondiente
console.log(btnBuscar.getAttribute('href'));
console.log(btnGenerar.getAttribute('href'));

});
```

```html
<form action="" id="form" method="POST" >
<select id="controlselect" name="ordenar">
    <option value='0' >Seleccione</option>
    <option value='1' >General</option>
    <option value='2' >Producto</option>
</select>

<!--<input type="submit"  id="BotonBuscar" onclick="Buscar()" value="buscar" />
<input type="submit"  id="BotonGenerar" onclick="Generar()" value="generar" />-->

<a href="" id="Buscar"><button type="button">Buscar</button></a>
<a href="" id="Generar"><button type="button">Generar</button></a>


</form>
```

**En PHP**

```
  <?php
//así obtenemos el valor por GET
$_GET['valor'];


    ?>
```

Comment: Perfecto , voy a probar la solución y te aviso.

Comment: Dale, éxito compañero! :)

Comment: Estoy haciendo la modificación respectiva , pero me esta arrojando error JS: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: Disculpa es que soy nuevo en esta web , gracias por la acotación.

Osea coloco mi código JS después de mi body es a lo que te estás refiriendo?¿

Comment: Si de esta manera <body>aquí va tu form, después del form y antes de la etiqueta de cierre de tu body o sea está --> (</body>)pones las de <script>//aquí va el código que te pase</script></body>

Comment: Perfecto , todo funciona , pero no me está mandando a las páginas , yo por ejemplo coloqué en los archivos PHP una simple impresión

$v1 = $_GET['valor'];

echo("Variable: $v1");

Pero no me está mostrando la nueva página con la variable que deseo imprimir.

Comment: Ponle el nombre de tus páginas correctamente yo las puse como entendí, pero tú ponle su nombre correspondiente, igual verifica que esas páginas estén en la misma raíz de tu proyecto, si están en otra carpeta tendrás que ponerle `carpeta1/nombredetuarchivo.php?valor=${valor}/`.

Comment: Mis archivos se llaman Prueba9.php y Prueba8.php y los programé así

 btnBuscar.setAttribute('href',`Prueba8.php?valor=${valor}`);
 btnGenerar.setAttribute('href',`Prueba9.php?valor=${valor}`);

Y están en el directorio raíz del proyecto.

Comment: Al oprimir el botón no te redirige a la página o sí lo hace pero no muestra nada? si sí te manda a la página podrás observar en dónde va la URL `Prueba9.php?valor=1` por ejemplo, si se visualiza?

Comment: Si , como te indiqué , el captura los valores cada vez que modifico mi combobox , pero cuando oprimo uno de los botones , se reinicia la consola y no se redirige a las páginas que le indiqué anteriormente.

¿Mi archivo actual es .html, debo cambiarlo a extensión .php y englobar todo el código en las etiquetas php?¿ o eso no tiene relevancia?¿

Comment: Ya vi el error, al button agregarle `type="button"` ya que por default hace como un `submit` y por eso no manda nada, con eso ya debe funcionar.

Comment: Funcionó muy bien , una pregunta rápida , si yo deseo que los valores seleccionados se mantengan , para cuando el usuario regrese a la página principal como haría, porque cuando yo le doy a un botón , perfecto y regreso nuevamente y le doy al otro , no capta , ni muestra el otro documento.

Comment: No va a captar porque el href se llena cuando haces el cambio del select, ahora si quieres guardar lo que seleccionó tendrías que usar `localStorage`, pero eso ya es harina de otro costal, si te sirvió mi respuesta marcala como aceptada, así cuando un compañero tenga el mismo problema sabrá cuál fue la solución.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias por tu atención y tu tiempo!!

Comment: Un gusto poder ayudarte! :D